# Simple way to understanding implementation of SHA-3 Keccak hashing algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, implementation, sha-3, keccak

I have been looking for references about the algorithm keccak on the internet, but none make me understand.

Here are some links that I found.

- http://plaintext.crypto.lo.gy/article/495/untwisted-a-cryptol-%20implementation-of-keccak-part-1
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3

Is there a way to understand the implementation or algorithm keccak easily? Is there a code on the PHP implementation for this algorithm?

Comment: Someone wrote [an extension](https://github.com/jedisct1/keccak-php) for it.

Comment: Yes, but how to understand this algorthm and how to implement psedeo code to `PHP`

Comment: It was the winner of a NIST competition, that's all I need to know really :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an official website of Keccak, which describes the alrgorithm in detail. It also explains and discusses the official code implementation.

http://keccak.noekeon.org/specs_summary.html

Someone took the time to implement a few Keccak implementations into PHP, worth a look:

https://notabug.org/desktopd/php-sha3-streamable